# Fabricjs detect hovered control box

Tags: fabricjs

I have a fabricjs canvas and onto that i am adding image. when we click the image the image is in selected mode.

is there a way to know if the mouse if over the grapples(the square boxed around the image) but not the one used to rotate?

and if it is can i fire a javascript command from there?

Comment: Do you want to disable rotation square?

Comment: yes, because then i can fire a javascript function when mouse is over the rotation square

Answer (score 0):

the rotation square is called 'mtr' inside fabricjs.

You can hook a 'mousedown' or 'mouseover' event to the object in this way:

`object.on('mouseover' myfunction.bind(object));`

the function you pass will receive an object parameter that we will call opt, just for example.

```
function(opt) {
  var mouseevent = opt.e;
  if (this.__corner === 'mtr') {
    callMyOtherFunction(mouseevent);
  }
}
```

this will not stop the rotation handling during `mousemove` or firing `modified` on `mouseup`

`this.__corner` referes to the object (this) and the last findTargetCorner result. Is not documented and is not a public feature, is mostly used for internal fabric logic, but is there and you can use it.

You should propose on the fabric issue tracker to make it an official feature, removing the double dash in front and documenting it in the docs.

Comment: which version of Fabric is this in? I am using 1.1 and i know its very old but upgrading to 1.7 caused some issues.

Comment: i have no idea how old is it. more than june 2014.

Comment: you should really upgrade if the project needs to go forward. 1.1 did not have zoom nor retina. svg import was bad.

Comment: right, but i have some code like this: canvasK.add(customImage); that has stopped working when upgrading to 1.7. the error is Unable to get property '_activeGroup' of undefined or null reference and i have no idea why this is happening?

Comment: no idea like that. you should open another question with a working snippet